# C GTK 3 Flow Box Items are moving when box expands

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm using a FlowBox inside a ScrolledWindow to show all the items in a game launcher program I'm working on. I want it to work like the icons in Thunar (the XFCE file manager) do. So when you expand the window, none of the items move, until there is enough room to add another column, at which point it adds the new column.

However currently, the items already on the row are moving further apart as the window gets larger, until there is enough room for another column at which point they snap back to normal spacing.

How can you prevent this from happening?